# vector bad allocation error c++

Tags: c++, stdvector, bad-alloc

I have been working on an avl tree that is vector based for quite some time. I'm suppose to take inputs from a file, but on the 4118 th input it gives me a bad_alloc error. I did some research and gathered inputs that I have to reserve space also. But even when I do allocate space, it still gives the same error.

parts of my code:

I call this function:

```
void insert(T d, unsigned int c = 1);
```

find(T d) finds the position of newNode in `vector<node<T>*> myVector`;
it will return a position even if it doesn't find newNode. Insert will take care of the returned integer (shown below)

insert is:

```
template<typename T>
void binaryTree<T>::insert(T d, unsigned int c)
//inserts type T with count c into vector
{
    node<T>* newNode = new node<T>(d,c);

    if(myVector.empty())
    {
        myVector.push_back(newNode);
    }
    else
    {
        int r = find(d);
        total++;
        //if newNode has same data as the data in position r
        if(r < myVector.size() && myVector[r] && *newNode == *myVector[r])
        {
            myVector[r]->data.loc.push_back(newNode->data.loc[0]);
            myVector[r]->count += newNode->count;
            delete newNode;
            return;
        }
        //insert into vector normally
        else
        {
            checkSpace(r);
            myVector[r] = newNode;
            //reParent(r);
        }
    }
}
```

with checkSpace being:

```
template<typename T>
void binaryTree<T>::checkSpace(int i)
//resizes the vector if needed
{
    if(i >= myVector.size())
    {
        myVector.resize(rightOi(i),NULL);
    }
}
```

and void reParent(r) being the main function that does all the rotate and balancing. 
I commented out reParent(r), and might have isolated the problem to be only in the insert function. I am fairly new to this, and I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

rightOi function:

```
template<typename T>
//return the right position of i
int binaryTree<T>::rightOi(int i)
{
    return i*2 + 2;
}
```

Comment: That looks incredibly inefficient. Don't call `resize` on a vector. Use `push_back` or `insert`.

Comment: Can you show your rightOi function?

Comment: ^done. It basically returns the position of the right child of a certain position.

Comment: It's very strange that you should run out of memory unless you're on some very limitied platform. Is it possible that you get into an infinite recursion which ends with you running out of memory?

Comment: So you're passing `newNode` in. What happens when its already in the tree? You value-compare the dereferenced node and the slotted node, and simply bump the count of the tree node. How does the *caller* know you did *not* insert `newNode` and thus they need to delete it? You return `void`, so I see no indication of the caller being informed `newNode` is still hot on their side and not owned by the tree.

Comment: Why would you have a vector of pointers if you use vectors as your base data container? (ie what's wrong with `std::vector<node<T> >`?)

Comment: @Simon: I have none recursions and an i7 win 8. It's also very strange to me.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'll be sure to rewrite that function in order to delete the raw pointer. Thank you.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, from what I can see, your implementation is not vector based; the vector you are using does not handle any node allocation, you are doing the allocations manually every time you want to insert a new Node (probably using `new`?), and I'd like to make sure you delete them properly. This is highly inefficient, vectors of pointers are not always simple to handle, and in this case I am certain they are unnecessary.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn vector<node<T>> is way too slow. If I recall correctly in class, it calls the copy constructor twice every time you use it... I may be wrong. But I have tried vector<node<T>>, and it is indeed very slow. By the way, void insert(int r, node<word> *newNode) is a private function. I'm rewriting it now to properly delete newNode.

Comment: @SamHuang What you recall about calling the copy constructor twice is when you return a `std::vector<node<T> >`. I'm not suggesting that you return a vector of nodes anywhere, the vector should be an attribute of your class that serves as a container (ie, vector-**based** implementation); in this case there is no reason that I can see when you'd have to call a copy constructor. If you came up with a slow implementation, I'd like to see it. If you're talking about the `node<T>`'s copy constructor, you should use references. If you're inserting new nodes by value, consider `emplace` instead.

Comment: @SamHuang I believe you when you say that your implementation was not efficient. This has nothing to do with using the right container (unfortunately). My advice is: go back to the right track, and then we'll see why it's not efficient. Vectors of pointers is definitely not the way to go, and this might be the root of your problems. It's not worth spending time fixing this.

Comment: I managed to fix it. The problem was with the checkspace. The size of the vector was too large and I had to resize it in a different way. It all works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the problem, which is that, the checkspace() function (which resizes the vector) gets the vector to resize to a huge number. That's why the program kept on giving me error. The fix for that is to resize only when necessary. Which is how I fixed my project.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, and slightly offtopic, but it seems to me, that vector isn't a good idea for dynamic trees, I'd create tree old-fashioned way, like this:

```
struct Node
{
    T value;
    Node* right;
    Node* left;
}

int main()
{
    Node<int>* root = new Node<int>();
    root->value = 10;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->left = NULL;

    Node<int>* someNode = new Node<int>();
    someNode->value = 5;
    someNode->right = NULL;
    someNode->left = NULL;

    root->left = someNode;
}
```

So it may be wrapped into functions like AddElement, Rebalance, Traverse, Delete by your rules. Ask if you need more detailed description.

Comment: I would rather create a binary tree with linkedlist, but the vector is required.